# Colocar mensagem de erro na view Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite galera.
Estou tendo dificuldade para retornar uma mensagem de erro amigável para
o usuário se ele tentar cadastrar um funcionário com um email que já esteja 
salvo no banco de dados, já que na minha tabela esse atributo foi "setado" como
unique.

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso personalizar isso no Laravel 5.6? Atualmente 
está retornando a mensagem de erro padrão que é essa aqui:

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'teste@teste.com.br' for key 'funcionarios_email_funcionario_unique'

Gostaria de colocar uma mensagem na própria view para o usuário, tipo assim:

"Email já cadastrado na base de dados!"

O caminho da exceção é esse aqui:

..vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

E esse é o tratamento da exceção:

```
 protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
    {
        // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually
        // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it
        // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.
        try {
            $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
        }

        // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
        // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        catch (Exception $e) {

            throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: você não está usando o validate do laravel?

Comment: Não. O validate seria uma feature do Laravel?

Comment: Sim, você define quais campos do form vc quer validar e que tipo de validação vai usar. segue a doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fera, o ideal é você fazer uma validação antes de persistir os dados.

No Laravel é bem simples, você pode criar uma custom request ou fazer a validação no próprio controller.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:funcionario,email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('funcionario/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
    }

    // continua e persiste os dados
    Funcionario::create($request->all());

    return redirect('funcionario/create')
    ->with('mensagem', 'Funcionário salvo com sucesso');
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, nesse seu código de exemplo seria diretamente no Controller correto? A mensagem de erro eu poderia especificar dentro do withInput()?

Comment: Sim, seria dentro do controller este exemplo.

O próprio Laravel irá se encarregar de produzir uma mensagem de erro quando você estiver utilizando o Validator.

Estas mensagens estão em /resources/lang/xx/validation.php

Comment: Caso queira que as mensagens de validação padrões do Laravel sejam em pt-br, eu sugeriria este [repositório](https://github.com/lucascudo/laravel-5.6-pt-BR-localization).